C# copy excel dropdown list
I have an already created dropdown list in cell A2. I want to use C# code to get that dropdown list from A2 and copy it to B2.
I've tried to do a few things to get this to work such as copying and pasting the cell and setting B2 validation to A2 validation.
Validation validation = worksheet.Cells[2, 1].GetValidation();
worksheet.Cells[2, 2].Validation.Add(validation);

However the code doesn't work.
Is there a way to get this to work?

I thought the drop down list is stored in the validation object.

You are correct, sorry for the distraction
